# Go Mod Download on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: go, github, nodes, raspberry-pi4, go-modules

Am running into a

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

error when running the following command from the below repository:

go mod download github.com/cih-y2k/wedeploy-gosocketio

https://github.com/kuoyaoming93/guardian-mainnet-guide/blob/master/docs/COMPILE_ARM64.md#install-guardian-node-from-source-code

Have deleted and re-downloaded the necessary directories, wasn't the solution.

Does this mean I need to download another language for this file to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to follow all the steps mentioned to use theta with arm64, otherwise you could be using the binaries from another arch like `amd64`.

I did a quick check in my raspberry and no problem reported, since the `go.mod` file has been replaced. with a new one with correct branches.

Finally, `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` means that you are using binaries that doesn't match with the current host architecture, in this case `arm64`.

```bash
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release  sed 's/v0.0.0-20200107021104-147ed25f233e/v0.0.0-20220216073600-600054663ec1/' go.mod > aux_file
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release 
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release  sed 's/github.com\/wedeploy\/gosocketio v0.0.7-beta/github.com\/cih-y2k\/wedeploy-gosocketio v0.0.8/' aux_file > aux_file2
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release 
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release  rm go.mod
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release ±  cp aux_file2 go.mod
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release ±  rm aux_file aux_file2
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release ±  go mod download github.com/cih-y2k/wedeploy-gosocketio
 pi@raspberrypi  ~/go/src/github.com/thetatoken/theta   release ± 
```

Since raspberry is Linux based you can use the following to verify the arch:

```
pi@raspberrypi  ~  arch ; uname -m
armv6l
armv6l
```

Go Env is also a check you should do:

```
pi@raspberrypi  ~  go env | grep -i ARCH
GOARCH="arm"
GOHOSTARCH="arm"
```

Comment: Great recommendation with detailed insight. How am I able to ensure that I am running with the arm64 architecture? Completed every step leading up to the error. Am currently working with the 128GB sim card preinstalled with NOOBS, running Raspberry OS.

Comment: Working with a Raspberry Pi 4, for sure would support this ARM64 structure. Thought that it would automatically be running as an ARM64. Is there a possibility that 'bash' is getting in the way?

Comment: Thank you again! Getting very close... Downloaded 64-bit Raspberry OS onto a new MSD and started from scratch. Made it all the way to the launch, and then ran into the cannot execute binary file: Exec format error once again. Then launched your tests as recommended:

Comment: thetaberry-t3@raspberrypi:~ $ arch ; uname -m
aarch64
aarch64
thetaberry-t3@raspberrypi:~ $ go env | grep -1 ARCH
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
--
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"

Comment: There must be a way to change the arch to the arm, correct?